# Update DatePickerDialog and TimePickerDialog to Current date and time

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

I am new to android and I am developing my 1st application for location based reminder where I am adding tasks with locations and date and time for which when I reach I should be notified. In the add task activity i have task name, location, buttons for date and time(when clicked DatePickerDialog and TimePickerDialog is displayed) and a AddTask button. 
When i give all the values and press the AddTask button i want to reset the DatePickerDialog and TimePickerDialog to the current date and time.
My problem is it is showing the values which i recently set for the task.. How to update the Dialog's.. plzz help..

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_task);
    init();

    /** Capture our View elements */
    //pDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayDate);
    pPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);

    /** Listener for click event of the button */
    pPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

   /** Capture our View elements */
    //pDisplayTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayTime);
    pPickTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickTime);


    /** Listener for click event of the button */
    pPickTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

    /** Get the current date and time */
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    pYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    pMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
     pDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    mHour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mMinute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
}

/** Create a new dialog for date and time picker */
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    pDateSetListener,
                    pYear, pMonth, pDay);

        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    mTimeListener,
                    mHour,mMinute,true);
    }
    return null;
}

public void add_task(View view) {

    Task task = new Task();
    task.setTaskNameString(activityForm.getTaskNameInput().getText()
            .toString());
    task.setTaskLocString(activityForm.getTaskLocInput());
    task.setTaskLat(activityForm.getTaskLat());
    task.setTaskLon(activityForm.getTaskLon());
    task.setDateString(activityForm.getTaskDateInput());
    task.setTimeString(activityForm.getTaskTimeInput());

    persistTask(task);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SAVED=" + task.hashCode(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    activityForm.getTaskNameInput().setText(" ");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save the instance of the dialog that's shown so you can access it later:

```
private TimePickerDialog mTPD;
private DatePickerDialog mDPD;

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            mDPD = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    pDateSetListener,
                    pYear, pMonth, pDay);
            return mDPD;

        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            mTPD = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    mTimeListener,
                    mHour,mMinute,true);
            return mTPD;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then afterwards you can change the shown date/time like this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
if (mTPD != null) {
    mTPD.updateTime(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
}

if (mDPD != null) {
    mDPD.updateDate(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}
```

Edit:

To modify the values set in the dialog you should play with the listeners that are available (which you already set). Here's an example (not tested):

```
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int curHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int curMin = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        if (hourOfDay < curHour) hourOfDay = curHour;
        if (minute < curMin) minute = curMin;

        mTPD.updateTime(hourOfDay, minute);
    }
};
```

Comment: Can i check for a condition that the user should not select previous date or time from the dialog's i.e the user should select current or the cumin date and time... ? If yes then how can it be done ?

Comment: I know it is a little off-topic but for date/time setting you can use this library https://github.com/jjobes/SlideDateTimePicker       , it will enable you to set the time and date in a single component and provide a great callback methods

Comment: @user2205230 updated my answer. If you have any more questions please ask another one.

Comment: @Simas i have asked my doubt here.. plzz help me i need help i ths.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405840/stop-user-from-selecting-past-date-and-time-in-datepickerdialog-and-timepickerdi